# Blackberry multiple MyApp-#.cod files when signing

Tags: blackberry, siblings, signaturetool

When I want to debug on device or just to sign my application when loading it on my device, I have weeks after weeks a growing number or COD files to sign... I'm now at 72! It means my RIM signatures quota, even if it is huge, it's going down very fast and I receive 72 emails every time I sign it.
I need to come back to the start, when I had maybe 4 of those, or one the MyApp.cod file only would be the best!

How to delete those? And from my SignatureTools?

I have also lots of files in my /deliverables/4.5 folder, with a bunch of MyApp-#.debug!

Please help me!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use svn ?
I think the .svn files is also included in your built jar, and so it grows larger everytime.
Tried by excluding the .svn files when you build your app.

Comment: I do, I'm using TortoiseSVN.
How can I exclude those .svn files when I build my app?
And by the way, if you know also how to not having .svn files in my /bin folder when I build, it would be great! Because of that, my root folder for my project is all the time red even if I don't have the /bin folder in my repository...

Thank you!

Comment: Ok, so see what I have done in Eclipse:
- Window > Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources and add ".svn"
- Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Building and add ".svn/" to the
filtered resources
- Project Properties > Java Build Path > Source and edit all the sources to
exclude (Exclusion pattern) **/.svn/.

It excludes the svn files in my bin folder so that's better. My jar file is still pretty heavy, and i have still 9 files MyApp-number.debug in my deliverable folder. I have now 30 signatures instead of 72 yesterday!

Any idea why i have so many sibling files and signature?

Comment: Update: I reduced my JAR file from around 2000KB to 325KB! Some useless images, etc. Then I have done this: Project Properties > Java Build Path > Source and edit all the sources to exclude (Exclusion pattern) **/.svn/. My .classpath is now updated and when I got my project from the SVN, no needs to do the trick again! So my SVN is working great and I don't have anymore the .svn folder into the bin and JAR.

Thank you!